# Sink drain slip joints leaking

Tags: plumbing, drain, leaks

I'm trying to install drain plumbing under my sink, and I can't seem to stop the slip joints from leaking.

Here's what I have right now (see picture):

- coming from the wall is a white plastic fitting
- very short piece of black plastic pipe (not really visible)
- 1-1/2" x 1-1/4" trap adapter
- approx. 6" piece of 1-1/4" tubing, most of which is inserted into the adjoining fittings
- 1-1/2" 45-degree elbow, with 1-1/4" adapter washers at both ends (see note below)
- 1-1/4" p-trap arm
- everything upstream from there seems to be leak-free (including the joint between the p-trap and arm)

[image]

I have leaks at the joints on both sides of the 45-degree elbow, and also where the tubing inserts into the trap adapter

I've taken all this apart and re-assembled multiple times, trying to be careful that everything lines up, but I always end up with leaks.  Part of the problem might be that when I try to tighten one joint, I end up accidentally twisting another one out of alignment.

Any advice on how to make this work without leaks?

<s>My current thinking is to replace the adapter + tube + 45-degree elbow with a 45-degree adapter. It would have to be a male (i.e., "street") fitting because there's basically no pipe left coming out of the white fitting to fit a female hub, and I really don't want to have to open the wall. If such a fitting exists, that would eliminate 2 slip joint connections.</s> (Edit: I realized a street fitting wouldn't work either. I think I'm stuck with the 1-1/4" adapter unless I open the wall.)

### A note about the 45-degree elbow:

The pipe from the wall is angled slightly downward, making an up-hill drain for a few inches. It's apparently been that way for years, and I'm not inclined to fix it (pun intended) unless someone here thinks it's a disaster waiting to happen. Rotating the 45-degree elbow slightly creates a straight connection for the p-trap arm.

Comment: I would change all the piping to inch and a half. Your problem seems to be the inch and a quarter pipe going into the inch and a half 45.  Is there a reason you didn’t go with inch and a half all the way.

Comment: @Alaskaman good point.  The existing trap adapter was 1-1/4", so I went with that, then ended up having to cut if off and replace it anyway.

Comment: A lot of people are under the incorrect impression that these are "hand tighten" fittings; they are NOT. Although I agree with @Alaska man in that 1 1/2" would have been right and proper, I will wager that if you tighten all that up with some Channel-lock pliers you're leaks will dry up...

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but I believe what you should do is use 1-1/2" plastic tubular for everything. In the US, [this 1-1/2" p trap kit made by Everbilt](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-1-2-in-White-Plastic-Sink-Drain-P-Trap-with-Reversible-J-Bend-C9704B/205153793) actually includes a reducing washer _which should be used on the sink tailpipe_ when inserting it into the j bend portion of the trap assembly. Don't use those reducing washers horizontally.